# Is there a jQuery method that determines whether an element is currently being animated or not in the form of a boolean?

Tags: jquery

The reason I ask is because I want to disable clicking of a show button WHILE the element it is animating is in the process of being animated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:animated` selector:

```
var isAnimated = $('#button').is(':animated');
```

http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: huh, clever. I knew of the animated selector but I didn't think to use it with .is

Answer (score 2):

```
if($("#someElement").is(":animated")) {
    ...
}

if($("#someElement:animated").length) {
    ...
}

// etc
```

So you can do:

```
$("#showBtn").attr("disabled", $("#someElement").is(":animated"));
```

http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/